# PostgreSQL вернуть значение

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы, актёры и руководители. В них написаны имена и страны проживания.
Нужно сделать функцию, в которой будет 2 входных значения (имя и страна). Если этот человек актёр-вывести 1, если руководитель-вывести 2, если такого нет вообще-вывести 3.

Вот что набросилось (только для 1го случая):

```
Create or replace function info(char,char) returns integer as $$
declare
    local_name char(20) := $1;
    local_country char(20) := $2;
begin
    if (local_name = actor.name and local_country = actor.country) from actor
    then return 1;
    end if;
end $$ language ‘plpgsql’;
```

Пишет, что select возвращает несколько строк.

Comment: Вам помог ответ, который я дал в прошлом вашем вопросе?

Comment: Да, я ещё сделал через similar(a,b)>0, так тоже работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
declare
  title integer;
  ...
begin
    select
      t into title
    from (
        select 1 as t
        from actor as a
        where a.name = local_name and a.country = local_country
        union
        select 2 as t
        from managers as m
        where m.name = local_name and m.country = local_country
    )
    limit 1;

    if found then
        return title;
    else
        return 3;
    end if;
...
```

Comment: А что такое 'actor'? Для чего это? И лимит в конце тоже зачем

Comment: Невнимательно прочитал вопрос. Исправил, хотя подозреваю, что можно сделать и лучше. Оператор `limit` нужен для того, чтобы в выборке было не больше одной строки, иначе `return` вернёт больше одного значения, а у вас в сигнатуре процедуры объявлено, что вернутся должно одно число.

Comment: Так, ну получается, что если этот человек есть и в актёрах и в руководителях, то выводится 2. Можно как-то либо пустое выводить, либо 4 например?

Comment: Ну то есть я добавил условия, в 1й и 2й where b.name<>local_country и подобные, но что-то не работают